# What else can cause "not-null property references a transient value"?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

My Grails 2.3.4 application has the following controller action:

```
def delete(Long id) {
    def bookInstance = Book.get(id)
    if (!bookInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'), id])
        redirect(controller: "book", action: "list")
        return
    }

    try {
        bookInstance.delete(flush: true)
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'), id])
        redirect(controller: "book", action: "list", params: [q: book.title])
    }
    catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'), id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: id)
    }
}
```

And these two domain classes:

```
class Book {

    static auditable = true

    String title
    static belongsTo = [author: Author]

    static mapping = {
        author ignoreNotFound: true
    }
}

class Author {

    static auditable = true

    String name
    static hasMany = [books:Book]
}
```

Please note the `author ignoreNotFound: true` as I'm dealing with a legacy database here. The above `delete` action allows for an 'orphaned' `Book` to be deleted.

Now, exactly the same WAR file of this application is deployed on two servers. Deleting an orphaned `Book` on one server works without a hitch. On the other server however, I get the following error:

> not-null property references a null or transient value: Book.author;
>   nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null
>   property references a null or transient value: Book.author

I have some understanding of what the error means, but given that the same code is being executed (and that the `Book` is orphaned in both cases) I'm lead to believe that there could be something else (apart from the action code) which is causing the problem on one server and not on the other.

Any idea what to look for?

Comment: try removing book from authors collection before deleting book and then save book and author

Comment: @sudhir there is no `author` (hence the orphaned `book`)

Comment: I want hear when you got a solution.

Comment: If it's working on one serve and not on another, I wonder if you've been changing the underlying database as you've been deploying versions?  Have you deployed the app more times to one system than to the other?  Have you changed the app in between deployments? What is the value of `dbCreate` within `datasource.groovy`?

Comment: @John the two databases are structurally the same. The app hasn't changed between deployments. No `dbCreate` specified.